# Why are some fields stable and other fields not stable?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory

Why are the fields that require hundreds of MeV or even GeV so unstable and those of tens to to a few million so stable?

An example would be the 174 GeV needed for the top field (unstable), and those that require only a few MeV for the down quark (stable)?

Answer (score 3):

A single particle can decay to multiple particles each of which has less energy (assuming other quantum numbers are conserved). A single particle cannot decay to multiple particles each of which has greater energy. This is basic energy conservation.

Comment: I am looking at why the higher energy fields are unstable...

Comment: @Rick ["Everything not forbidden is compulsory."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totalitarian_principle)

Comment: The fields themselves aren’t unstable. One single top-quark quantum field pervades the universe and always will. It doesn’t disappear. Its excitations or quanta, top-quark particles, are unstable because they have enough mass to decay into other quarks with less mass. Top quarks do disappear, but the quantum field they were excitations of continues to exist. This is just how quantum field theory works.

Comment: You seem to have the idea that there is a top-quark field for every top quark. That’s not the way QFT works.

Comment: I understand the field is for all specific particles.  I was using a single top quark as an example.